# Why does the android jetpack NavigationUI navigateUp method only open the draw menu if you are at the start destination of the nav graph

Tags: android, navigation, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer, android-jetpack

When using a `NavigationView` with a `DrawLayout` and an `ActionBar`, `jetpack` provides some powerful convenience methods to hook everything up together so that these items are easier to implement.

The method `setupActionBarWithNavController` provided in the `NavigationUi` library is an extension method for activities that adds a hamburger button to open your drawer and if you override the `onSupportNavigateUp:Boolean` method on your activity to call `navigateUp(drawLayout:DrawLayout, navController:NavController)` method, that method will change the hamburger button to a back button and back automatically with a fancy animation, which is super cool.

However it seems that this method is implemented as follows:

```
 public static boolean navigateUp(@Nullable DrawerLayout drawerLayout,
        @NonNull NavController navController) {
    if (drawerLayout != null && navController.getCurrentDestination().getId()
            == navController.getGraph().getStartDestination()) {
        drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    } else {
        return navController.navigateUp();
    }
}
```

As you can see here, this method has the basic logic of:

*if you are not at the start destination of the navgraph, then the button is a back button, otherwise its a hamburger button*

This means that only the start destination can open the draw menu via an actionbar button, while all the other destinations have a back button instead, and must swipe to open the draw menu.

Why is this the case? It seems this is a conscious design decision by the android team. Is it frowned upon to have a hamburger button available on multiple destinations?

I would like to have a few main branches that have a hamburger menu and all the screens that branch of from those to have a back button. Is there a way to implement multiple `NavGraphs` and link them together in one `NavigationView`?

u_u

Comment: I would also like to know this. None of the Google apps work this way, so why did they change the expected behavior?

Comment: Have you managed to solve your problem? I have looked into the source code of `NavigationUI` class and used that code to achieve multiple top level destinations. I can post the code as an answer if you are interested.

Answer (score 1):

I reported a problem I had with the use of a Toolbar inside a fragment and the `NavigationUI` helper in [bug 109868820](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109868820).

The Googler that helped me indicated clearly (article #7):

> [...] the discussions with the material design team has made it clear that the navigation drawer is a global navigation pattern that should be available everywhere

So the material design drawer has to be available on every screen, including the deeper ones when the navigation button is the "up" arrow (not the hamburger). In which case, the drawer is only available from a swipe gesture, as the navigation button navigates up in the app stack.

Indeed (#4 in bug):

> You'll still get the title set from the android:label in your navigation graph and proper behavior when it comes to the Up button (particularly important if you're using the DrawerLayout versions)

So the behavior that you found in the source is indeed the "proper" behavior.

Hence:

- top level destination: drawer opened through swipe and hamburger button
- non-top level destination: drawer opened through swipe only, button navigates up (no hamburger)

In other words, the hamburger button should only be used on top-level destinations.

Comment: Unfortunately I think that many users would be oblivious to the fact that you can swipe the drawer menu out without some indication that its there. Are we meant to have a tab on the left to indicate that the drawer menu is accessible? Perhaps there is some other way to inform the user that the drawer menu is there?

Comment: Users come to your top-level destination where they discover the drawer through the hamburger icon. Then, they know you app has a drawer and they open it with a swipe.

Comment: Unfortunately there can only be one top-level destination currently (start destination), so the hamburger button is only visible in one fragment and not all top level destinations. Unless I have missed something and have set up the Drawer on Navigation controller incorrectly.

Comment: What do you mean all top level? There can be only one!!! (pun) My understanding is launcher = top level (hamburger), all other screens are second level (no hamburger)

Comment: @BenoitDuffez Google apps have many top level destinations. For example look at Gmail app. Top level destinations are: Inbox, Sent, Drafts... to name a few. All have the hamburger icon in the action bar. In general top level destinations are reached from the drawer (hamburger menu). Their child destinations are second level (no hamburger).

Comment: Fair point. Then I should rephrase "hamburger button should only be used on top-level destinations" to "...be used on _main_ fragments, that you would need to detect at run time (using a `switch` statement on the ID, for example)".

Comment: The point of OP's question is that combination of Drawer and Navigation component does not work as intended or in other words you cannot achieve more than one top level destination. Hopefully they will fix this in the future releases, otherwise the usefulness is quite limited.

Comment: Yes you are right. I didn't think of this case because my current apps don't need more than one destination with a hamburger. My answer was more a share of a find rather than a comprehensive reply.